# How do use conduct an analysis of variance test for three models contained in a tibble of list-columns?

Tags: r, tidyr, anova, tibble

Hi: I have data set of 10 dependent variables and three independent variables.  I'd like to do an OLS on each separate dependent variable , adding each independent variable in sequentially. So, using tidyr I get a tibble of models.

I;d like to run the analysis of variance for each dependent variable, testing the the nested models against each other. But how do I do that in the context of a tibble of models?

```
library(tidyr)
#Fake data, two dependent variables, two independent variables
dv1<-rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
dv2<-rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=3)
iv1<-rnorm(100, mean=100, sd=20)
iv2<-rnorm(100, mean=100, sd=20)
#make a data rame
df<-data.frame(dv1, dv2, iv1, iv2)
#save in model.list
model.list<-df %>% 
  #gather the dependent variables
  gather(variable, score, -iv1, -iv2) %>% 
  #group by dependent variables
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  #run the model against each of the dependent variables, sequentially, first with iv1 then with iv1 and iv2
  do(model1=lm(score~iv1, data=.), model2=lm(score~iv1+iv2, data=.))
```